# Determining dependencies between C functions based the use of their arguments?

Tags: c, pointers, gdb, static-analysis

I have a large C program, and I am trying to find out which functions (given a list of functions) depend on each other in terms of their arguments.

For example, say I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PEOPLE 100

typedef struct
{
  int id;
  char name[50];
} person_t;

static person_t people[MAX_PEOPLE];

void addObject(int id, const char *name);
void incrementID(int id);

int main(void)
{
  addObject(1, "bob");
  incrementID(1);

  printf("ID: %i\n", people[1].id);
  printf("Name: %s\n", people[1].name);
}

void addObject(int id, const char *name)
{
  people[id].id = id;
  strcpy(people[id].name, name);
}

void incrementID(int id)
{
  people[id].id++;
}
```

addObject and incrementID have a dependency with each other since one of their arguments (id) is saved to the same array. Therefore, the functionality of one will depend on the functionality of another.

Given source code, or a binary, I want to be able to generate these dependencies automatically.

My idea is to analyze a binary compiled with the -g flag and determine which regions of memory will be modified by each function. Any functions which modify the same region of memory are "dependent". I'm not sure if this heuristic will work, or where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: Your problem sounds a lot like information flow analysis - this type of technique can be used in a security context to prove something like "x software never gives away its private key". You could see if there are any tools for this that may help.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to generate these dependencies automatically.

You may want to give up: your problem is equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

For any particular *execution* of your target program, with a sufficiently capable tracer, you can derive whether functions `A()` and `B()` access / modify the same memory.

But that will only tell you facts about that particular *execution*, not about the program *in general*. Any change in input arguments may modify the execution, and therefore the facts you deduce.

Answer (score 0):

GDB is probably wrong tool for this kind of problem. You want to build a call graph for your program to analyze dependencies between functions. One way to do it is to use Eclipse CDT Indexer to show callers of `people` array. You can select `people` variable and open call hierarchy for it. You will see that it is used in `addObject()` and `incrementID()` functions and therefore they can depend on each other:

[image]